# python sys.path:How can i permanently remove an incorrect site-package from sys.path?

Tags: python, sys.path

I'm using python2.7 and python3 in my mac.But i accidentally add python3 sitepackages in to python2's sys.path like below.

sys.path:

[image: sys.path]

When i tried to use pip installing numpy for python2,i got this

pip install error:

[image: pip install error]

After trying lots of ways solving this problem,i thought the best way is to permanently remove the error python3 site-packages from sys.path.
However,i couldn't find a way to remove it.
What can i do to solve thsi problem?
Thanks for answering.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't paste links to images of your `code / error messages`. It would be much better to copy/paste your  `code / error messages` into your question, including what line gives you that error. Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How and where are you adding this? It's probably a simple `PYTHONPATH` manipulation error in your `.bashrc` or similar but we can't see it.

Comment: Try to output your PYTHONPATH variable first to see what's in there: `echo $PYTHONPATH` or `python -c "import os; print(os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH'))"`

Comment: Yes,i was adding this through .bashrc by accident.So now in my PYTHONPATH of python2.7,i'm having the site-packages of python3.And it seems that the python3's site-packages is in higher priority than python2's site-packages,while i was trying to use pip install something, it would automatically install into python3's sitepackages,which really confusing me.So how can i resolve this problem?I'm trying to remove python3's site-packages from my PYTHONPATH,but have nerver found a way to do so,thx!